# java serialization socket inputstream flush

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, flush, objectinputstream

I have a java client that is constantly every 33 ms updating a class in my game program. the problem is when i open two clients that receive the same class and should be synced they have different results depending on who started or made contact with the server first. Then after the values never change but i (now) know the server is sending out the write class to both. In my  tutors lecture notes it says to do it like this

```
ObjectInput input;
input  = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
serializableobject = (cast) input.readObject();
input.flush();
```

which is how i was taught but now ive come to implement it (didnt need this at uni) it doesnt work. Ive spent literraly weeks and months trying to work out why and today think i cracked why but dont know how to fix it. Bassically from the start input.flush(); doesnt seem to exist for ObjectInput or ObjectInputStream so I left it out and tested it and my class was displayed lovely using break point to verify my server class was sent and set all the variables of my games settings class. the problems come on the next update of this class from the server but its taken me ages to work out. What i believe is happening (if not im gunna give up)is that it reads the very first object sent and holds it in the input stream. Then when i call the same method it continually just gives me the 1st object back again. Im assuming this is because i dont flush it like my tutor says in the lecture slides. The outputstream has a flush which i use. I also have looked in both ObjectInput and ObjectInputStream and wasent able to see flush or an alternative or a way of moving on to the next object in the stream. the latter i dont think would be a good idea anyway becuase the stream will just continual grow until possibly running out of memory i assume. anyway heres my receiving class and my server.:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class BaseServer 
{
        private String result = null;

        //for serializable class input stream
        ObjectInput input;


     // Declare client socket
        Socket clientSocket = null;         

     // Declare output stream and string to send to server 
        DataOutputStream os = null;


     // Declare input stream from server and string to store input received from server
        BufferedReader is = null;
        String responseLine;

    //get ip
        String serverAddress ;                                    

    // Create a socket on port 5000 and open input and output streams on that socket
    public void  setUpNetwork(String serverAd)
    {          
        try
        {
            serverAddress = serverAd;
            clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddress, 5000);

            //string
            os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());          
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            //serial
            input = new ObjectInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream() );

        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
        }      
    }

    /*
     * Used to communicate with server
     * takes message to send and the object expecting the response
     * 1 simple method to replace all but one of the below v1 methods
     */
    public BaseSerialDataObjects serverTalk(String message){
        sendStringMessage(message);

        try {   
            BaseSerialDataObjects bSO =  (BaseSerialDataObjects) input.readObject();            

            return  bSO;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    ////////Old v.1 methods for interacting with servers. I have now changed my mind
    //and am using strings to send messages and serializable objects as return messages 
    //I have left these in as I have plans to reuse the most of the code in this game

    public String read(){
          // Write data to the socket
          if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null)
            {
             try
                {                           
                    os.writeBytes("ok \n");

                    return is.readLine(); // my bit   
                }
                catch (UnknownHostException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
             }
          }
        return responseLine;
       }          

    //Sends messages to the server
    public void sendStringMessage(String message){
        // Write data to the socket
        if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null){
            try {                        
                os.writeBytes( message + "\n" );                                 
                }
            catch (UnknownHostException e){
                System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
                }
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
                }
            }   
        }          

    /*
     * V.1 method idea am leaving in for an option in future games
     */
    public  String getStringResult(String returnMessage)
   {    
       String tempHolder = read();
       if(tempHolder!=null)
       {
       String[] array = tempHolder.split("\\s+");
       if(array[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(returnMessage))
       {
           result = null;      
           tempHolder = "";

          for(int i = 1; i < array.length;i++)
          {           
              tempHolder = tempHolder +  array[i] + " ";        
          }
        return tempHolder.trim();
       }
       else return null;
       }
       else
         {
           return null;
           }

   }   

    public synchronized void setResult(String res)
    {
       result = res; 
    }    

    public void closeConnections()
   {
    // Close the input/output streams and socket
       try{
        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close(); 
       }catch(Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println("Exception: " + e);
       }
   }
}
```

the line: BaseSerialDataObjects bSO =  (BaseSerialDataObjects) input.readObject();

is the one where i put a breakpoint on the return bSO line below and it always shows a class with the same values as the first even though ive just put breakpoint on server and checked its got different values just before returning the class which makes the client hang while i inspect it so i know its the right thread and class and everything

Server :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TCPserver implements Runnable 
{
    static Socket server = null;    

    private static final int possibleNumberOfPlayers = 8;
    private static final int amountOfPlayerInfoHeld = 6;
    private int threadNumber;

    private static ServerSettings gameSettings = new ServerSettings();
    private static int numberOfSettings = 4;

    //position 0 = name;
    //position 1 = angle;
    //position 2 = position x
    //position 3 = position y
    //position 4 = state

    //position 5 = state in relation to server
    //POssible states: 
        // connected
    static PlayerPositionsSerial positions = new PlayerPositionsSerial();

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       positions.playersArray = new String [possibleNumberOfPlayers][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld];

      // Declare a server socket and a client socket for the server
      ServerSocket service = null;

      // Try to open a server socket on port 5000
      try
       {
         service = new ServerSocket(5000);
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t0 = new Thread (new TCPserver(0));
           t0.start();
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t1 = new Thread (new TCPserver(1));
           t1.start();
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t2 = new Thread (new TCPserver(2));
           t2.start();      
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t3 = new Thread (new TCPserver(3));
           t3.start();
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t4 = new Thread (new TCPserver(4));
           t4.start();          
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t5 = new Thread (new TCPserver(5));
           t5.start();
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t6 = new Thread (new TCPserver(6));
           t6.start();          
            server = service.accept();
            Thread t7 = new Thread (new TCPserver(7));
           t7.start();
            /*server = service.accept();
            Thread t8 = new Thread (new TCPserver(8));
           t8.start();  */      


      }
      catch (IOException e)
       {
         System.out.println(e + "Error B");
      }        


        }

    public void run()
    {
    // Declare an input stream and String to store message from client      
        BufferedReader is;
        String line;

        // Declare an output stream to client       
       DataOutputStream os;

        String thr = Integer.toString(threadNumber);

      // Create a socket object from the ServerSocket to listen and accept
      // connections. Open input and output streams
      try
       {
            ObjectOutput output;
            output = new ObjectOutputStream( server.getOutputStream() );

            is = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
                                         server.getInputStream()));



           //if( (line = is.readLine()) != null )
            while( (line = is.readLine()) != null )
            {
                if(line != null)
                {                   
                    switch(rules(line)){
                    case "playertable": 
                        output.writeObject( positions );    

                        break;
                    case "gamesettings": 
                        output.writeObject( gameSettings );
                        break;
                    case "servernumber": 
                        StringReturnSerial string = new StringReturnSerial();
                        string.s = Integer.toString(threadNumber);
                        output.writeObject(string);
                        break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("line didnt select anything");
                            break;
                    }
                }output.flush();

            }

            // Comment out/remove the stream and socket closes if server is to remain live. 

         is.close();

      }  
      catch (IOException e)
       {
         System.out.println(e + "Error B");         
      }         
    }

    public TCPserver(int tNumber)
    {
        threadNumber = tNumber;
    }

    private synchronized void changeArray(int row, int col, String value)
    {
        positions.playersArray[row][col]  = value;
    }

    private synchronized String readArray(int row, int col)
    {
        return positions.playersArray[row][col];
    }   

    private String rules(String lineIn)
    {
        try {
             String[] splitArray = lineIn.split("\\s+");

                 switch(splitArray[0])
                 {
                    case "SIGNIN":

                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][0] = splitArray[1];
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][4] = "normal";
                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld-1] = "connected";                       
                        addPlayer();
                        gameSettings.gameStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;

                        return "gamesettings";

                    case "ok":
                    // just for reply, do nothing response heard "ok"
                        break;
                    case "MATCHMAKE":
                            positions.playersArray[threadNumber][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld -1] = "matchmake";
                            gameSettings.gameState = "matchmake";
                            return "playertable";

                    case "READY":

                        positions.playersArray[threadNumber][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld -1] = "ready";

                        return "gamesettings";


                    case "REQUESTSTART":

                          boolean goAhead = true;
                            for(int i = 0 ; i < gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers; i++)
                            {
                                if(positions.playersArray[i][amountOfPlayerInfoHeld-1] != "ready")
                                {
                                    goAhead = false;
                                }
                            }                       

                            if(goAhead)
                            {
                                long start = System.currentTimeMillis( );
                                start = start + 10000;
                                gameSettings.gameStartTime = start;
                            }

                            return "gamesettings";

                        case "GETPOS":

                            return "playertable";                           

                        case "UPDATEPOS":

                            //heres where to notice crashes and check for wins etc...
                            positions.playersArray[threadNumber][1] = splitArray[1];
                            positions.playersArray[threadNumber][2] = splitArray[2];
                            positions.playersArray[threadNumber][3] = splitArray[3];
                            positions.playersArray[threadNumber][4] = splitArray[4];
                            return "playertable";

                        case "GETSETTINGS":
                            return "gamesettings";

                        /*case "SENDSETTINGS":

                            // updates settings 
                            for (int i = 1; i < splitArray.length; i++){
                                switch(i){
                                case 1: 
                                    gameSettings.gameState = splitArray[i];
                                    break;
                                case 2: 
                                    gameSettings.winningNumberOfLaps = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[i]);
                                    break;
                                case 3: 
                                    gameSettings.winString = splitArray[i];
                                    break;
                                case 4: 
                                    gameSettings.gameStartTime = Long.parseLong(splitArray[i]);
                                    break;
                                case 5: 
                                    gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers = Integer.parseInt(splitArray[i]);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            returnString = "gamesettings";
                            break;
                            */

                        case "GETSERVERNUMBER":
                            return "servernumber";                          

                        case "PLAYING":
                            gameSettings.gameState = "playing";

                            break;
                        case "SERVERPLAYERSTATEUPDATE":

                            int crashed = 0;
                            positions.playersArray[Integer.parseInt(splitArray[1])][5] = splitArray[2];
                            for(int i  = 0; i < gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers;){

                                //takes into account possibility of people leaving game
                                if(positions.playersArray[i][5] != null){
                                    if(positions.playersArray[i][5] == "explode"){
                                        crashed++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if(crashed == gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers)
                                gameSettings.gameState = "explode";

                            return "gamesettings";  

                        default:
                            System.err.println("Rule Not Found: " + splitArray[0]);
                            break;

                 }

        } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {

                System.err.println("error C: " + ex);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public synchronized void addPlayer()
    {
        gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers++;
    }

    public synchronized int getNumberOfPlayers()
    {
        return gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers;
    }

    public synchronized void removePlayer()
    {
        gameSettings.numberOfConnectedPlayers--;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance JOhn harris

Comment: I'm wondering how do you really flush an input stream?!!

Comment: Lol are you asking the same question as me or are you saying mine is a silly question?

Comment: You don't flush an input stream.  "Flush" just mean push any bytes remaining int the *output* buffer to the underlying hardware (disk, network, etc) that the stream is attached to.  Thus it is only applicable to output.

Comment: It wouldnt surprise me if it was something stupidly simple, the things that get me the most always are

Comment: any ideas why i get the same then @keith

Comment: so basically as its on the slides as having a input.flush my teacher was completely wrong? @keith

Comment: Yes, wrong.  Unless "input" was a reference to an OutputStream.  :-)

Comment: @user2120315 would you please just comment out the sections in your code are related to getting and sending data?

Comment: I would start by verifying that the serialization of BaseSerialDataObjects is working. (Or including the code for that class in this question).  One possible explanation is that you have custom serialization code in that object, which has a bug, resulting in **any** object deseriazing to the same thing.  So, in this case, a different object could be sent, but perhaps always deserialized to the first.

Comment: @user2120315 Well I think this is normal if clients are not synchronized, because in the server, you just accept 8 client and for each request response a result, so this is okay if client 1 is unsynched with client 2, the approach you have selected is not good, because only client has to signal for the new state, while server should sync clients for any events in order to sync clients with each other, and would you point the _every 33 ms_?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be reusing the same static socket reference **server** in each thread.

You want to use the new socket created upon each accept:

```
Socket newSocket = server.accept();
```

and pass that to each thread:

```
Thread t3 = new Thread (new TCPserver(3, newSocket));
```

Inside of TCPserver then, use **ONLY** the reference to newSocket.

To force you to do this, get rid of this declaration:

```
 static Socket server = null;
```

and just make it a local variable in your main method:

```
 Socket server = new ServerSocket(5000);
```

---

Here is a server from one of my programs:

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

private void acceptConnections() {
    listening = true;
    while (listening) {
        try {
            final Socket connection = serverSocket.accept();
            System.err.println("SERVER - connection from: " + connection.getInetAddress());
            executorService.execute(new ConnectionHandler(connection));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

It uses a thread pool, instead of creating a new thead each time, but the basic idea is the same.  My "ConnectionHandler" class is equivalent to your "TCPserver" class.

Comment: Good answer, but check the server code, in run method it waits for the command from the client then response the requested response, this is naturally unsynchronized, also every properties are belong to each client and server session, so there is no any shared member belong them for synchronizing responses with each otehr

Comment: @user 2511414, I had trouble parsing your english, not clear what you are saying.  At a quick look I don't see any synchronization problems, as there is a unique instance of TCPserver, and all of its non-static fields, for each client.  If you see a problem indicate the specific line.

Comment: @Keith thank you for ur proposed answer this would be useful especially if players come and go obviously. Would this solve my real problem that has had me rewriting this ten+ times? which is why does input.ReadObject wait for the server to respond and when it does just return the first object it asked for. This first object always comes back correctly.

Comment: its like after the first use of input.readobject its useless?

Comment: I think it could solve the problem yes.  Previously if a second client connected, say client #2, the server would write its new instance of gameSettings to the *same* socket used by client #1.  which might explain why cilent #1 was seeing a fresh gameSettings multiple times.

Comment: at the moment client #1 connects and receives and passes the at that time correct gameSettings class. client #2 connects and the same happens, so there different but were right at the time of asking. then for both they ask again and although the newer then both gamesettings gets wrote to the server output stream which i can check just before its flushed which is correct. but neither update again

Comment: i will try your solution as it will probably be an improvement on my implementation :) but not sure it will solve my probs. will get bacj to you soon

Comment: would this matter, on all the serislisation classes Ive got this warning : The serializable class ServerSettings does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long

Comment: That warning will not matter, as presumably in this case, both client and server are using the same version of the serialized class.  If you ever use a slightly older version on one side, then you might have to set serialVersionUID to force it to work (but in the case that it doesn't work, it fails with an exception at runtime).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `flush`, you need `reset` (in [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)).  Object streams, read and write, save everything they read and write.  Two problems:  One, you run out of memory on both sides.  Two, if you send the same object twice, the object read will contain the data of the first read.  The second time, the write just sends the object ID (essentially), not the data.  Call reset after each call to `writeObject`.